# How to follow constantly a keyword in multiple files and include filename beginning of each reported line

Tags: tail

```
tail -f a/b/c.log d/e/f.log
```

logs like this:

```
==> a/b/c.log <==
xxx
yyy
Exception happened 1
zzz

==> d/e/f.log <==
rrr
Exception happened 2
sss
```

How to change command so that the lines containing "Exception" are picked up like this:

```
a/b/c.log: Exception happened 1
d/e/f.log: Exception happened 2
```

The solution can use any Linux commands.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? If the files are all in directories in that same pattern and you are only looking for that string, then what's wrong with `grep -H "Exception" */*/*.log`? If the pattern is actually different from your example, then you'll need to adjust it.

Comment: The command should follow constantly new lines coming to the files

Comment: 1) You question needs to specify that. One can put it together after your comment but with the way that it's written, it looks like you just want a way to get that output. 2) Edit the question and add what you have tried so something similar is suggested. It's also important to show that you've made an effort rather than asking others to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [`multitail`](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) installed you could use it with `-E`  to select only lines that match a certain regex and with `--label` to prepend those lines with the filename e.g. (adjust `-N 0` per your needs):

```
multitail --follow-all -N 0 --mergeall -E 'Exception' \
--label 'a/b/c.log: ' a/b/c.log --label  'd/e/f.log: ' d/e/f.log
```

If don't have access to `multitail`, you could just `tail -f` each file and post-process the output with tools like `grep`, `sed`, `awk` e.g.

```
tail -f a/b/c.log | sed '/Exception/!d;s|^|/a/b/c.log: |' &
tail -f d/e/f.log | sed '/Exception/!d;s|^|/d/e/f.log: |'
```

or

```
tail -f a/b/c.log | awk '/Exception/{print "a/b/c.log: " $0}' &
tail -f d/e/f.log | awk '/Exception/{print "d/e/f.log: " $0}'
```

Comment: I don't have possibility to install multitail

Comment: @MikeRapsen - ok, see edit

Comment: tail -f a/b/c.log | sed '/Exception/!d;s/^/a/b/c.log: /'

causes error

sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'

I have my own real folder structure and file. It can affect to error message.

Solution

tail -f a/b/c.log | awk '/Exception/{print "a/b/c.log: " $0}' &
tail -f d/e/f.log | awk '/Exception/{print "d/e/f.log: " $0}'

works

Comment: @MikeRapsen - yes, my mistake, I used files in the current directory for testing and I forgot to change the delimiter of the substitution when I replaced their names with your sample paths (and those contain `/` hence the error). It should work now.